# Background image shows up on simulator but not device?

Tags: ios, objective-c, image, sprite-kit

I'm working on an IOS app and my background image shows up perfectly on the iPad simulator, but not on the actual device? Is there a reason for this??

This is my code:

```
    if (IsPad) {
        SKSpriteNode *bg = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"padBG"];
        bg.position = CGPointMake(self.frame.size.width/2, self.frame.size.height/2);
        bg.zPosition = -3.0;
        [self addChild:bg];
    }else {
        SKSpriteNode *bg1 = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"iphoneBG"];
        bg1.position = CGPointMake(self.frame.size.width/2, self.frame.size.height/2);
        bg1.zPosition = -3.0;
        [self addChild:bg1];
    }
```

Is there any reason why the image is not showing up on the actual device? The image has been properly imported into my project as padBG@2x.png, and `IsPad` is defined in my pch as:

```
#define IsPad      (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() != UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone)
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The default OS X file system is case-perserving but not sensitive, while the iOS file system is case sensitive. Are the images named exactly as your wrote the, including case? If not, they will show in the simulator but not on the device.

Comment: @JasonCoco 100% the same

Comment: Try deleting the app from the iPad, cleaning the project, then rerunning it.

Answer (score -1):

Try to add if it's a .png or .jpg after the imageNamed:@"padBG.png";p

Comment: It's a retina image, the @2x is to make sure it works as its supposed to.

Comment: No. If using SpriteKit that is not needed. You just need the image name. The system will figure out which resolution to use.